# Need help converting this indicator to version 5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So I've been trying to convert this script into version 5 from version 1/2, and I can’t figure it out, I am not that experienced with old version under v4.

```
//@version=1
study(title = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", shorttitle = "SuperTrend ATR + RSI", overlay = true)

//Mode
Factor=input(title="Super Trend", defval=3, minval=1,maxval = 100)
ATR=input(title="ATR", defval=7, minval=1,maxval = 100)
RSI = input(title="RSI", defval=7, minval=1, maxval = 100)

//Super Trend ATR
Up=hl2-(Factor\*atr(ATR))
Dn=hl2+(Factor\*atr(ATR))

TUp=close\[1\]\>TUp\[1\]? max(Up,TUp\[1\]) : Up
TDown=close\[1\]\<TDown\[1\]? min(Dn,TDown\[1\]) : Dn

Trend = close \> TDown\[1\] ? 1: close\< TUp\[1\]? -1: nz(Trend\[1\],1)
Tsl = Trend==1? TUp: TDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? green : red

//RSI
src = close,

ep = 2 \* RSI - 1
auc = ema( max( src - src\[1\], 0 ), ep )
adc = ema( max( src\[1\] - src, 0 ), ep )
x1 = (RSI - 1) \* ( adc \* 70 / (100-70) - auc)
ub = iff( x1 \>= 0, src + x1, src + x1 \* (100-70)/70 )
x2 = (RSI - 1) \* ( adc \* 30 / (100-30) - auc)
lb = iff( x2 \>= 0, src + x2, src + x2 \* (100-30)/30 )

//Affichage
plot(avg(ub, lb), color=purple, style = line, linewidth=1, title="RSI")
plot(Tsl, color = linecolor , style = line , linewidth = 1,title = "SuperTrend ATR")
```

I’ve tried to do everything within my knowledge to try to unlock this.

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you need help? Do you get some errors or what?

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
//Crée par J.Dow
//SuperTrend ATR, Le type ATR calcule la volatilité à partir de l'Average True Range (ATR), il est idéal pour le FOREX
// Le RSI et idéal pour voir la force d'un mouvement
indicator(title='SuperTrend ATR + RSI', shorttitle='SuperTrend ATR + RSI', overlay=true)

//Mode
Factor = input.int(title='Super Trend', defval=3, minval=1, maxval=100)
ATR = input.int(title='ATR', defval=7, minval=1, maxval=100)
RSI = input.int(title='RSI', defval=7, minval=1, maxval=100)

//Super Trend ATR
Up = hl2 - Factor * ta.atr(ATR)
Dn = hl2 + Factor * ta.atr(ATR)

TUp = 0.0
TDown = 0.0
TUp := close[1] > TUp[1] ? math.max(Up, TUp[1]) : Up
TDown := close[1] < TDown[1] ? math.min(Dn, TDown[1]) : Dn

Trend = 0.0
Trend := close > TDown[1] ? 1 : close < TUp[1] ? -1 : nz(Trend[1], 1)
Tsl = Trend == 1 ? TUp : TDown

linecolor = Trend == 1 ? color.green : color.red

//RSI
src = close

ep = 2 * RSI - 1
auc = ta.ema(math.max(src - src[1], 0), ep)
adc = ta.ema(math.max(src[1] - src, 0), ep)
x1 = (RSI - 1) * (adc * 70 / (100 - 70) - auc)
ub = x1 >= 0 ? src + x1 : src + x1 * (100 - 70) / 70
x2 = (RSI - 1) * (adc * 30 / (100 - 30) - auc)
lb = x2 >= 0 ? src + x2 : src + x2 * (100 - 30) / 30

//Affichage
plot(math.avg(ub, lb), color=color.new(color.purple, 0), style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, title='RSI')
plot(Tsl, color=linecolor, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=1, title='SuperTrend ATR')
```